# PySpark: applying custom string match function on a crossjoin dataframe taking too long

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe `df1` and has ~400K records. I am performing `crossjoin` with another dataframe `df2` that has ~21K recoerds.

```
df_cross = df1.crossjoin(broadcast(df2))
```

Now I am applying a string match function to find similarities between two columns from `df1` and `df2`. The similarity is measured and stored in another column `matchScore`. Then rows with`matchScore` < 0.80 are filetred out. The `df1` has also an Index column named `RN` which was created as:

```
df1.withColumn('RN',F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id()))-1)
```

The whole process is executed in the below code block:

```
split_range_val=[(i,i+100000-1) for i in range(200000,df_f.count()) if i%100000==0]
for li_val in split_range_val:
  df_f= df1.filter((col('RN')>=li_val[0]) & (col('RN')<=li_val[1]))
  df_cross = df_f.crossJoin(broadcast(df2))
  df_cross = df_cross.repartition(96)
  df_cross=df_cross.withColumn('matchScore',StringMatch(col('col_df1_1'),\
           col('col_df2'),lit(2)))
  df_cross = df_cross.filter(df_cross['matchScore']>0.80)
  df_cross.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').\
           mode("append").option('header','true').csv(dest_adls+"/curatedFinal")
```

My databricks cluster has 1 driver and max 5 workers totaling 48 cores. Each worker node is of 32GB RAM and 8 vcores. Hence I thought of repartitioning the cross dataframe within loop by `2 x # of cores`. Despite this, the code is not writing any output to destination ADLS storage.

And it has been running for 4 hrs!!!

Is there any way we can improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

First, your window is not partitioned. This makes it very slow: the row number adding is done only on the driver. However, the biggest problem is the loop. Instead of letting spark doing the parallelization and use resources optimally, you're limiting spark to doing it piece by piece. So remove the loop (then you also don't need the windowing, row numbers, repartitioning, broadcasting.. anymore). Speed is also dependent on the stringmatch function, which you didn't show. But I'd expect it to be much faster with your resources.

Comment: I actually realized that repartition is not appropriate within for loop. Also, this `for loop` is not correct approach. I have found a way to work this around and I am going to update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways the code can be optmized:

### Caching

```py
df_f= df1.filter((col('RN')>=li_val[0]) & (col('RN')<=li_val[1]))
```

By caching `df1` before the loop, you can avoid that dataframe being evaluated every single loop (remember dataframes are lazily evaluated).

### Reduce Shuffling

Every loop, you are shuffling data around twice -- once with `.repartition(96)` and again with `.repartition(1)`. Explicit repartitioning for the `96` case is probably doing more harm than good with Databricks since the Databricks Runtime already does a good job automatically optimizing the number of partitions. Furthermore, ~400k records, while it does not reflect the physical size in bytes, is still quite small. And of course repartitioning to a single partition is naturally going to be slow because it has to shuffle all of the data to a single executor.

### TL;DR Use Spark

The loop in general can be tossed out. Let Spark do the heavy lifting for you.

```py
# No loop... No window function... No repartitioning... 
df_cross = df_f.crossJoin(broadcast(df2)) \
  .withColumn('matchScore', StringMatch(col('col_df1_1'),col('col_df2'),lit(2))) \
  .filter(df_cross['matchScore']>0.80)

df_cross.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').\
  mode("append").option('header','true').csv(dest_adls+"/curatedFinal")
```

Answer (score -1):

So finally I had used the following approach:

```
spark.udf.register("StringMatchUDF", StringMatchUDF) #<---to make the string match function as temporary udf so that we can use that in spark.sql
repart_factor= 2
num_partitions = repart_factor*48 <---# twice the number of available cores
df_f = df_f.repartition(num_partitions)
df_cross = df1.crossJoin(broadcast(df2))
df_cross.createOrReplaceTempView("df_cross") #<---creating a view essentially eliminates the need of Window() function for creating Index. 
df_c_f = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM df_cross WHERE 
               StringMatchUDF(df1_col_1,df2_col_2,2) > 0.80""")
df_c_f.write.format("com.databricks.spark.parquet").\
option("header","true").mode("append").parquet(dest_adls + "/curatedFinal")
```

What I also realized that unless it is necessary, we should not create `index` in spark dataframe. With the above code, I got rid off performance bottleneck and `for loop` which as per the comments are highly undesirable.